# The image in an HTML file is very blurry and out of focus

Tags: html, css

I am working on an html file. I want to display an image across the entire page in a div with a height of 200 px. The image is quite big, so it should occupy the width of the page without any repeat. The size of the image is 5760 X 3840 pixels. The following is how I have styled my div:

```css
div {
  background-image: url('C:/MyFolder/MyImage.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The problem is that the image shows up very blurred. As shown in the code I even used the image-rendering attribute, but didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: That seems like an excessively large image for that usage. I pity your mobile users if they have any data limits/charges. From your code there is no scaling going on. It is hard to tell without an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You can instead of setting background img for the div you can add a img inside the div and make it stretch to the size of the div then using z-index make it appear as a background image(be sure to include position relative or else z index won't work). Setting background of a div is good if the image is the same size as the div else it never looks right.

```
    <style>
      .background-img {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          position: relative;
          z-index: -1;
     }
   </style>
   <div> 
     <img src='/your-image' class='background-img'/>
   </div>
```

Or possibly a solution you could try with your example is adding background-size cover to your styles.

```
 <div style="background-image:      url('C:/MyFolder/MyImage.jpg'); background- repeat:no-repeat; height:200px; width:100%; image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; background-size:cover"> </div>
```

Hope this may look better

Comment: Hi radlaz, this worked really well except one issue. I don't want the height to be 100%.When I changed the height to 200px either in the img  element or in the div, the image looks distorted. Is there any way to see the image of the desired height without distortion. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it looks but try adding overFlow:hidden; on the img

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1:**

If you are comfortable to replace `div` with `img` tag. Then your code becomes

```html
    <img src="your-image.jpg" class="customImgSize"/>
```

Then apply the styles like

```css
    .customImgSize {
     width: auto;
     height: 200px; /* your custom height */
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

You can achieve the result by using an `img` tag. Then wrap the `img` tag with a `div`.

```html
    <div class="imgContiner">
      <img src="your-path-to-image" class="flexibleImg"/>
    </div>
```

And your CSS becomes

```css
    .imgContainer {
      width:auto; 
      /* you can use max-width/min-width to define the widths for all */ 
      resolutions
    }

    .flexibleImg {
      width: auto;
      height: 200px; /* Apply your height */
    }
```